# Error while installing memcache (1.2.13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, memcached

when i try to install memcache (1.2.13) on ruby 1.9.2 on OSX 10.8 i'm getting the following error-message:

Part of the error-message at the beginning:

```
An error occurred while installing memcache (1.2.13), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install memcache -v '1.2.13'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And at the end:

```
ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [native_server.bundle] Error 1
```

It seems to be the same problem like this one: [Error when installing memcache gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485890/error-when-installing-memcache-gem/19909446#19909446) but there are no answers :-(

I hope the information is enough and someone of you can help me. This problem costs me already a few days!

Thanks for any solution-ideas!

Comment: This might help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150208/error-installing-memcached-gem-on-snow-leopard-wrong-architecture

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but i have trouble by installing memcache and not memcached. The error is different too ... any other suggestions? :(

Comment: so i think the problem is displayed in this line:

ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1

maybe a path couldn't be resolved. but i don't know what "-lruby.1.9.1" means ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i solved the problem (thanks to Justin Balthrop)! I downgraded the memcache gem version to 1.3.0 and now everything works fine!

Watch also at this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1216521

Or maybe try a different memcache client like: https://bugs.launchpad.net/libmemcached/+bug/1216521

Good luck! ;-)